# ¿Cómo obtener las fuentes de un proyecto Java?

Tags: java

¿Existe alguna manera de poder recuperar las fuentes de un proyecto por medio de un archivo .war?

Comment: Podrías usar un de-compilador y hacer ingenieria inversa, aunque también es cuestión de ética si no es tu proyecto. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La única opción podría ser usar un descompilador (realizar ingenieria inversa) por ejemplo mediante una breve búsqueda:

- http://jd.benow.ca/
- http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui
- http://www.javadecompilers.com/
- https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui
- http://www.neshkov.com/dj.html

Mas información:
[Cómo recuperar el código fuente de Java del proyecto archivo .war](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/indijava/pybTE2j_Zz8) (en inglés)

Existe una pregunta similar en SO en inglés:
[How do I “decompile” Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)

Comment: ¿esto podrian ser las dos caras de la moneda? http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2489/c%C3%B3mo-proteger-c%C3%B3digo-fuente-java :) Saludos

Comment: De acuerdo contigo @AngelAngel de hecho aquí aplicaría algo llamado ética, desgraciadamente no hay método de ofuscación infalible. Esperemos que nuesto amigo Edgar Conrado use esta información para sus propios proyectos jeje!, saludos!

Comment: @AngelAngel ironías de la vida. No se puede proteger el código por completo. Lo mismo se aplica aca, no esperes que los decompiladores te entreguen las fuentes originales del proyecto, estos programas harán su mejor esfuerzo por obtener el código a partir de javap. Si las clases son simples pues no habrá problemas pero si tu código es complejo el decompilador tampoco hará magia